# Capturing null value from form data in laravel

Tags: laravel

I send `FormData()` with axios in laravel, but even if `language is null` it is validated, it should not be possible. why can it pass validate when it is empty?
is there any way to prevent this?

```
title: hello
language: null
image[]: (binary)
```

```
$request->validate([
            'language' => 'required',
            'image.*' => 'image|mimes:jpg,jpeg,png',
        ]);
```

Comment: try to dd the $request->all() object and see if lang is actually sent or not.

Comment: yes 'language is empty' but it can pass validator

Comment: add type of language in rule , ex: 'language' => 'required|string'